# Uso da expressão "do mesmo"

Tags: gramática

A seguinte frase:

Estas geometrias são simplificações da disposição dos átomos, os quais são os vértices das mesmas.

Está correta? Fiquei confuso com o uso da expressão "das mesmas" enquanto queria me referir as "geometrias" da primeira frase.

Comment: Lucas, peço desculpas se houver ofensa, mas por que achas que estaria errada? A frase é realmente meio confusa, mas esse simples fato não a torna errada.

Answer (score 1):

**Não tá errado.**

Todavia...

Não gosto muito de usar "dos mesmos" para retomar termos antecedentes nos textos que escrevo. Eu acho que soa um pouco mal, e também vejo muita gente usando, então tento outra coisa para fazer diferente e manter a língua viva. Neste caso, apesar de julgar brusca a transição entre *geometria* e *vértices* (vértices do quê?), supomos que pelo contexto esteja claro: são vértices de figuras geométricas formadas pelos átomos.

Existem dois termos sequenciais no texto bem próximos uns dos outros, e queremos nos referir a um deles (ou aos dois). Nessas situações, é correto utilizar os pronomes demonstrativos como "*Este... mas aquele...*" ou mesmo "*O primeiro... já este último...*", (eu lembro-me do inglês *former* e *latter*). É possível fazer referência a [três fatos](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Eariadne/mo901/1s2012/este-esse-aquele.pdf) citados no texto simultaneamente:

```
 O primeiro [fato] que foi citado: aquele
 O do meio: esse
 O último citado: este
```

Há duas opções, a meu ver:

1. Mantemos o ponto final e nos referimos a "*átomos*" através de termos como "*Estes últimos*", "*Tais partículas*", "*Eles*" etc.:

> *Estas geometrias são simplificações da disposição dos átomos. Estes últimos, por sua vez, figuram como vértice dessas formas [geométricas].*

> *Estas geometrias são simplificações da disposição dos átomos. Coincidentemente, tais partículas compõem/integram o vértice daquelas estruturas (piramidais, tetraédricas etc.).*

> *Estas geometrias são simplificações da disposição dos átomos. Eles representam os vértices das complexas formas geométricas, [enquanto as ligações simbolizam as arestas ou algo do gênero]*.

2. Mantemos a sua construção de oração subordinada adjetiva, recorrendo aos pronomes relativos para referir-nos aos corpúsculos. Vamos trocar "das mesmas" por "seus":

> *Estas geometrias são simplificações da disposição dos átomos, que representam seus vértices.*

> *Estas geometrias são simplificações da disposição dos átomos, os quais representam seus vértices.*

Sobre essas últimas formulações dá quase para pensar que "*seus*" se refere a "*átomos*", já que os termos estão bem próximos no período. Porém, sabemos que os átomos mesmo não têm vértice, mas sim as formas geométricas em que se organizam. Ainda, eu usei "*representam*", pois, na sua oração, você mencionou que as geometrias são "*simplificações*", o que me faz inferir serem apenas representações dos átomos, e não cópias perfeitas de sua organização espacial num dado instante.

Comment: Sanzio! Muitíssimo obrigado pela resposta!